# Composer doesn't work

Tags: windows, composer-php

I have a problem after installing "Composer" for Windows. I have installed it with the installer for windows and added the path.

But when I typ: composer in CMD nothing shows up, Just an empty rule.

[image: screenshot]

Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a misconfiguration with your PHP. Run the following command to check for any such misconfigurations:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check
```