# Why does Composer not work when PhpStorm is on?

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm 2022.2 and very new to this IDE and language.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278237/composer-doesnt-work) and tried the command.

When I try
`curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --check` in my cmd while not using PhpStorm,
it goes

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
All settings correct for using Composer
```

which looks fine except the Xdebug message.

But when I try it with PhpStorm program on, I see
this on my cmd, which just stops doing nothing, can't even type another commands. I have to exit that cmd to enter other commands.

[image: this]

This goes the same with other commands - just typing `composer` in cmd also goes the same. Doesn't work when PhpStorm is on, works with Xdebug message on the top when PhpStorm is off.

My PhpStorm settings with Composer looks like this, have fixed Execution from 'composer' executable to composer.phar and browsed the path but doesn't work anyway.

[image: this]

Couldn't find the same problem. Other peoples not-working composer does nothing but letting them to type other commands differ to mine, not even letting me use the cmd window again.

Comment: Did you enable "Break at first line" for XDebug? Why not simply disable XDebug when using Composer?

Comment: What does it mean by enabling "Break at first line" for XDebug? My php.ini file has ```xdebug.mode=debug``` and ```xdebug.start_with_request=yes```, and PhpStorm Settings - Debug - Force break at first line when ~ two are all checked

Comment: It does exactly what the option says: it stops the execution at the very first line of PHP code that PhpStorm detects

Comment: Do you mean Enabling "Break at first line in PHP scripts" at: PhpStorm - Settings - Php > Debug - External connections?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the two way of setting it. But once more: why not simply disable XDebug when running Composer? Or do you want to debug any problem within Composer itself?

Comment: That was because I didn't know that I could disable XDebug while running Composer. I just know that Xdebug is a tool to debug PHP code, and Composer a tool to manage dependencies... No more. I didn't know that they are causing problems to each other.

Comment: Based on your 1st sentence you don't need this complex IDE software and dependency manager for you at the moment. Learn the basics first, an online PHP sandbox service is perfect for this, you don't even need to install a server environment on your computer (for example WAMP): [PHP tester online](https://extendsclass.com/php.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you start `composer` on the command-line, you actually also start `php`.

And `php` you have configured to start a step-debugging session (with `ext-xdebug` per `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` and `xdebug.mode=debug`).

Now unless Phpstorm is running this is fine as you get the timeout message.

But when Phpstorm is running, there will be no timeout as the connection is not timing out any longer - the debugging client (in Phpstorm) is listening and accepting the connection.

But here is the caveat: If a debugging session in Phpstorm is already running and not yet finished, Phpstorm puts the other ones in a waiting state.

This is what you experience, it looks like as if the `composer` command hangs.

Your options: Check with the documentation of the debug extension and the debug client for options to control this behaviour, e.g.

- Raise the number of maximum simultaneous connections in Phpstorm, compare [Simultaneous debugging sessions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/simultaneous-debugging-sessions.html) (read the whole page, it should give a fair amount of good impression where your current setup is unconfigured at most)
- Use the [`XDEBUG_MODE` environment parameter](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode) in the environment you invoke the `composer` command, e.g. by setting it to `off`. Consult your operating systems shell programming manual on how to set an environment parameter value.
- Reconsider your current use of `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`, it should not be on (but off) by default in the PHP CLI SAPI, set it conditionally in CLI only for the PHP Development Servers you need it with (`php -d xdebug.start_with_request=yes -S ...`), compare *[Using PHP from the command line](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)*.